# How to prevent key combo subset from overriding superset in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to autohotkey, but can't seem to find a way to stop this

How do I prevent a key combination subset from over-riding the windows default superset?

I want to bind `Rwin+Right` to `Alt+Tab` without breaking the default `Ctrl+Rwin+Right` desktop switching

Answer (score 1):

```
; Rwin+Right
>#Right::                 ; ># means RWin
    AltTabMenu := true    ; assign the Boolean value "true" to this variable
    Send {RWin Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}
return

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (AltTabMenu)         ; If this variable has the value "true"

    ; The tilde prefix (~) prevents AHK from blocking the key-down/up events
    ; The * prefix fires the hotkey even if extra modifiers (in this case Alt) are being held down
    ~*RWin Up::             
        Send {Blind}{Alt Up} ; release Alt
        AltTabMenu := false
    return

#If
```

**EDIT:**

Added `{RWin Down}` to the command `Send {Alt Down}{Tab}` because of

> [v1.1.14+]: If the [tilde prefix](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) is applied to a custom modifier
>   key (prefix key) which is also used as its own hotkey, that hotkey
>   will fire when the key is pressed instead of being delayed until the
>   key is released.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde

Comment: Interestingly, while I can find no problems with this, it doesn't work for me. `RWin` + `Right` does nothing on my machine. I added a `Sleep , 500` between the `AltTabMenu := true` and `Send {Alt Down}{Tab}` which seemed to work, but then `alt` gets stuck down. Everything in your code looks fine and should work, so I'm not sure why I'm having issues with it.

Comment: This one behaves strangely for me. It worked initially but then Windows becomes unresponsive to keypresses and some mouse inputs. I can still logout though.

More generally, it's odd that a two key combination from autohotkey supersedes Windows' default three key combo (that I begin with a different key)

Thanks anyway, I guess I must spend more time with the manual

Comment: Yes, that cleared it up for me. Smooth as butter; nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be even simpler than that:

```
#Right:: Send {Alt Down} {Tab}{Alt Up}
#^Right:: Send {Ctrl Down}{Rwin Down} {Right} {Rwin Up}{Ctrl Up}
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't account for releasing the modifier keys that you have set to a down state.